# How do I subtract some values based on the text value of a different column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have a spreadsheet that is tracking payments between 2 people. It looks like the following:

[image: Spreadsheet]

I'm looking to subtract the value of the `Amount` column from the retrospective persons `Left to pay` amount, depending on whos name is picked from the dropdown in the `Who paid?` column.

For example - `E5` has a value of `Jill`. `D5` has a value of `£500`. Because `E5` has `Jill` as it's value, I would like the value of `D5` to be taken away from Jills left to pay value in cell `I5`.

I know I would need to use an `IF` formula but I can't quite figure it out. Is anyone able to advise on how this would be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the 2500 fixed value?
If yes, try this formula:

```
=25000-SUMIF($E$5:$E$12,H4,$D$5:$D$12)
```

[image]

If no, add the auxiliary cell:

```
=$H$1-SUMIF($E$5:$E$12,H4,$D$5:$D$12)
```

[image]

Comment: Accepted as managed to get it working using this method, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to have "initial" `Left to pay` value stored in some cell and then calculate value like this:

```
LeftToPay = InitialLeftToPay - SUM(AllPaymentsOfPerson)
```

Try to not use horizontal tables (Left to pay) it is not how Excel (and others) are meant to be used. I suggest to format your tables ([named tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-format-tables-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664) and [renamed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-an-excel-table-fbf49a4f-82a3-43eb-8ba2-44d21233b114) tables are used) like this:

[image]

Then formula in `Left to pay` column is

```
Office 365 
=[@[Initial value]]-SUM(Payments[Amount]*(Payments[Who]=[@Who]))

Older versions
Array formula has to be used. Formula above must be confirmed by CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER
```

### How it works:

```
Payments[Who]=[@Who]
```

Compares value from `Left to pay` table column `Who` in same row where formula is with whole column `Who` in `Payments` table. Result is array (same size as `Payments` `Who` column) with `TRUE/FALSE` values.

If you use `TRUE/FALSE` values in numeric calculation they are treated as `0/1` values.

```
{"Jill","Jack","Jill","","",""}="Jack"
={FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}={0,1,0,0,0,0}
```

Therefore:

```
SUM(Payments[Amount]*(Payments[Who]=[@Who])
```

Is `SUM` of `Payments` `Amount` column values multiplied by result of previous step (treat array with values `1` or `0`).

```
SUM({250,500,100,0,0,0}*{0,1,0,0,0,0})
=SUM({0,500,0,0,0,0} )=500
```

And finally this sum of "wanted" `Ammount` values is substracted from `Initial value`.

```
=25000-500=24500
```